# Rails 5 entity path helpers method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading to Rails 5.0.0.beta4, I get an 'undefined method' error when trying to send an email using the Rails path helpers.  I have an ActiveRecord class called `Project` and I am trying to send an email containing a link to the projects page using the path helper `project_path(project.id).  Prior to Rails 5 this used to work.

Here is the ERB for the link:

```
<%= project_path(@project.id) %>
```

I'm using ActionMailer to send the email.  Any ideas on what might have caused this problem after switching to Rails 5?

Comment: Have you tried running `rake routes` to see the available path methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 4.2 allowed this feature as a carryover from Rails versions past; however, Rails 4.2 explicitly discouraged it via documentation in the [Rails 4.2 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-mailer).  This documented discouragement is called *deprecation*, and is used as advance notice that a feature will break code in a subsequent release.

The entire purpose of deprecation is to allow the feature to continue working in the current versions, so as not to disrupt productivity.  Feature-wise, this is how the architecture, libraries, and even the language move forward in a controlled manner.  Note that security issues do *not* follow the deprecation process, and are fixed *in situ* in order to eliminate vulnerabilities as quickly as possible.

Rails 5 was the version that actually removed the ActionMailer support for `_path` helpers, which had previously been deprecated.  The [Rails 5.0.0.beta1 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta4/actionmailer/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-rails-500beta1-december-18-2015) shows that the break was made then.  The [pull request](http://github.com/rails/rails/pull/15840) was merged in Rails 5 RC1 with [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bd944e078d0f40e26d66b03da1449ff9cdcc101b).

Answer (score 1):

Path helpers have apparently been removed for emails in rails 5. The new syntax is as described by DickieBoy `project_url` which gives the whole url instead of just a part of the url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Rails 5, it could be, someone please correct me if i'm wrong.

Imagine you are opening an email. You see a link to something, oooh let me click it.

*click*

`file:///projects/1` appears in the browser window. Eh? Thats weird. Let me try it again.

`file:///projects/1` ah, i see the problem this person has tried to put the path of a website into an email.

**TL;DR** Use `project_url` not `project_path`.

Comment: The url is prepended to the string I'm having problems with and that works. There problem occurs before the email is sent and causes a crash when rendering the email. It is not a path problem.

Comment: That is the email is not sent because of this error.

Comment: Sorry its because of the narrative in the answer is not a structured answer also it was indeed a change in rails that caused this.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson from the rails docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views "_Because of this behavior you cannot use any of the *_path helpers inside of an email_"

Comment: If you correct your answer I will up vote it and check it.

Comment: What has http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views got to do with Rails 5, or deprecations? This guide references the current stable version (`4.2.6`), and the behaviour has been unchanged for years.

Comment: @TomLord not sure who your comment was aimed at but; guides. has very little to do with the Rails 5 release, but knowing that `*_url` helpers shouldn't be used in the current version and it doesn't make sense for the to work in Rails 5, as you said: "The behaviour has been unchanged for years"

Comment: @DickieBoy the problem with the answer is that it suggest nothing is wrong instead of a feature having been removed. Yes there is nothing wrong but when upgrading from 4 to 5 that is not helpful information. More over as we provided the server address in our link with other means there was no reason to suspect the link should have directed the user to file://.